# Как выводить из строки IP адреса(regex)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ip, вывод, match

В общем дело такое. Программа должна вывести из строки все ип адреса. Может быть там нужно создать цикл, т.к. она выводит только 1 ип адрес. Иными словами, она должна вывести всё кроме "0.0.0.0.0 asdasdad"

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Application
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {




        string text = "213.123.11.0 455.121.123.123 0.0.0.0.0 asdasdad ";

        }
        Regex r = new Regex ("\\b[0-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]\\b");
    Console.WriteLine(r.Match(text));
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В каком языке укажите тег: ECMA-262 (JavaScript), Java, C...

Answer (score 1):

В Unix shell

Из всего файла или stdin:

```
~$ IPV4_RE="(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"

~$ IPV6_RE="([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){7}|::|:(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,6}|[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,5}|(?:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){2}(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,4}|(?:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){3}(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,3}|(?:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){4}(?::[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,2}|(?:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){5}:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}|(?:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,6}:)"

~$ grep -oP "$IPV4_RE" input_file
~$ grep -oP "$IPV6_RE" input_file
```

из каждой строки в отдельности:

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo $line | grep -oP "$IPV4_RE"
    echo $line | grep -oP "$IPV6_RE"
done < input_file
```

**Ссылки**

- https://regex101.com/library/dT0vT3
- https://regex101.com/library/rB9pG1